# How to play a pure PCM raw stream with C#?

Tags: c#, pcm

I was looking into System.Media.SoundPlayer and NAudio, and AFAIK they only play WAVE streams. The WAVE file is composed of the pure PCM data plus a format header.

I don't want to provide this header in the WAVE format. I want to pass the parameters (bitrate, etc) programatically

Comment: Do you want to play a WAVE file that is missing the WAVEFORMATEX header? Then you have to guess about the number of channels, the bitrate, and the number of bits per sample... Or do you want to find a reference of this header? The documentation is here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd757720(VS.85).aspx

Comment: @Andreas I want to be able provide this info programatically, outside the stream

Comment: Using the native Windows API (waveOutOpen, waveOutPrepareHeader, waveOutWrite, and so on), it is possible to play the waveform data of your choice. However, I am not very knowledgeable in the .NET world...

Comment: @Andreas I think I can access this API from C#, thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As I said in the comment above, using the native Windows API (waveOutOpen, waveOutPrepareHeader, waveOutWrite, and so on), it is possible to play the waveform data of your choice. I make this an answer so that it can be accepted in case it actually is what the OP is looking for.